# Rule score not visible for each rule in Google Pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I was going through google pagespeed and thought of giving a try. I went through a couple of tutorials to learn about the same. 
In the tutorials they showed that each rule had an associated `score` parameter. However, the response that I got has only a `ruleImpact` parameter for each rule and no `score` parameter.

This is what I used :

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https://www.google.com&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

And this is the response I got (not showing the entire response but only the first few lines)-

```
{
 "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
 "id": "https://www.google.com/",
 "responseCode": 200,
 "title": "Google",
 "score": 99,
 "pageStats": {
  "numberResources": 11,
  "numberHosts": 4,
  "totalRequestBytes": "2159",
  "numberStaticResources": 9,
  "htmlResponseBytes": "114193",
  "imageResponseBytes": "46012",
  "javascriptResponseBytes": "857355",
  "otherResponseBytes": "210",
  "numberJsResources": 5
 },
 "formattedResults": {
  "locale": "en_US",
  "ruleResults": {
   "AvoidLandingPageRedirects": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Avoid landing page redirects",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your page has no redirects. Learn more about avoiding landing page redirects.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/AvoidRedirects"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "EnableGzipCompression": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Enable compression",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "You have compression enabled. Learn more about enabling compression.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rule impact is the "score" so to speak for the specific rules.

> The impact (unbounded floating point value) that implementing the suggestions for this rule would have on making the page faster. Impact is comparable between rules to determine which rule's suggestions would have a higher or lower impact on making a page faster. For instance, if enabling compression would save 1MB, while optimizing images would save 500kB, the enable compression rule would have 2x the impact of the image optimization rule, all other things being equal.

This means that based on the recommendations being made, the ruleImpact of each are relative to each other in terms of how much of an impact that rule violation has on the score.